# Custom facebook share button is not working properly

Tags: asp.net, facebook

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://localhost:8821/EventRegister.aspx" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Welcome and Share Test" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Hope it worked!!!!!!!" />
```

I am developing an asp.net project and wanted to put a facebook share button in it. I wrote that code in head /head part and then started the debug mode and tried the link:
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://localhost:8821/EventRegister.aspx

But all I got is a empty share page with no title or description only just the localhost link in description.

How can I make it work? I want customizable title, image, description like in the above code. I have been looking for it for 2 days non-stop.

Thanks...

--

UPDATE:

```
<a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=sfgsfgsfg&amp;p[summary]=sdgsdgsdg&amp;p[url]=http://localhost:8821/EventRegister.aspx','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">Click to share.</a>
```

did this and still same result :(

Comment: it just won't work no matter I change it...

Comment: I think its not working on localhost, so I need to get my project online to test with the facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is working after I created a free host on myasp.net... :) Do not debug any facebook code on localhost as it won't work because facebook cannot access to your local machine unless you have some workarounds.

Comment: Moreover, facebook is not updating the meta tags information for the page immediately, you have to wait for 24 hours or https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug do this. Yet Im looking for something more rapid.